# powershell - simulate Windows-D to clear and restore screen

Tags: powershell

I have a request to get a screenshot of users desktop icons.  I can use Powershell to capture, but need to clear the screen first, take the shot, then restore the screen.  Keystrokes 'Windows+D" will do it, but the Windows key is not an option to simulate in Powershell.  Is there another way to capture a screenshot of the desktop?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a solution that also takes the screenshot. I'm using that in my scripts where I need to screenshot something. why automate only parts of the task, when you're also able to automate everything ;-) right?

```
# Take Screenshot function - reads width and height from WMI, saves in outfile path
function Take-Screenshot([string]$outfile) 
{
    [int]$PrtScrnWidth = (gwmi Win32_VideoController).CurrentHorizontalResolution
    [int]$PrtScrnHeight = (gwmi Win32_VideoController).CurrentVerticalResolution
    $bounds = [Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB(0, 0, $PrtScrnWidth, $PrtScrnHeight)
    $bmp = New-Object Drawing.Bitmap $bounds.width, $bounds.height
    $graphics = [Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bmp)
    $graphics.CopyFromScreen($bounds.Location, [Drawing.Point]::Empty, $bounds.size)
    $bmp.Save($outfile)
    $graphics.Dispose()
    $bmp.Dispose()
}

# Minimize all the Windows
$shell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
$shell.minimizeall()

#sleep to make sure not to screenshot while everything is still minimizing
sleep -s 2

# Take the Screenshot - choose your outfile path
Take-Screenshot -outfile C:\Batch\test4.png

# get your screen back
$shell.undominimizeall()
```

Comment: That's brilliant!   Thanks, it's the 'minimize all windows' that I needed.  I don't see how you found that, no way to trace what the 'Windows+D" actually calls.  Thanks so much!!

Comment: SimonS, if you're still there, how can I change the line "Take-Screenshot -outfile C:\Batch\test4.png" to a variable? Everything I've done so far result in an error at the "$bmp.Save($outfile)" line, stating ""The path is not of a legal form"". Depending on where it is run from, I need to change the path. Thanks again!

Comment: @JCauble you could do something like this `$outfile = Z:\somewhere\somewhat.png` and then `Take-Screenshot -outfile $outfile`

Comment: @JCauble if you mean the name of the screenshot itself should be variable, you could add a DateTime or `$env:computername` like this `$DateTime = (get-date).tostring('yyyyMMdd-HHmmss')` and then `Take-Screenshot -outfile "Z:\somewhere\somewhat-$DateTime-$env:computername.png"`

Answer (score 1):

There is example [here](http://techibee.com/powershell/powershell-minimize-all-windows/1017) .

> I came across this little tip while exploring shell.application com object. It has other useful functions like undominimizeall, cascade windows, and many other explorer functions.

```
$shell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
$shell.minimizeall()
```

> You can also undo minimize all windows by using below code.

```
$shell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
$shell.undominimizeall()
```

Comment: SimonS, if you're still there, how can I change the line "Take-Screenshot -outfile C:\Batch\test4.png" to a variable?  Everything I've done so far result in an error at the "$bmp.Save($outfile)" line, stating ""The path is not of a legal form"". Depending on where it is run from, I need to change the path.  Thanks again!

Comment: YES!  That's exactly what I needed!  I don't know why I couldn't get it to work before, but I am learning, and really appreciate these tips.